# How to post large object as a string using Axios?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, axios

I need to be able to post a VERY large/complex object as a string so that I can immediately save it to disk as a json file on the server.  I don't want to have to map it to an object in C# and then turn right around and serialize it to disk when I don't need to interact with the object on the server at all.

The issue is, sometimes the string breaks the post.  To get around that, we used to `encodeURI` the string after the `JSON.stringify` but then we have to `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` it in C#.  That has some unwanted consequenses on some of the data (like it removes the pluses inside dataurls for image src attributes inside some HTML in properties).  How can we post the object as a string without the errors or unwanted side-effects?

OR... is there a way to post as an object and then in C# receive it as a generic object that can be serialized without mapping it to a class first?

```
var data = {
    workflowID: workflowToSave.ID,
    jsonWorkflow: JSON.stringify(workflowToSave)
};

vm.axiosPost("/Workflows/Save", data).then((result) => {
    
}) ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the btoa initially (see my other answer) and it worked for the most part but still had some minor issues so I switched it over to use [base64-js](https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js) and everything works perfectly now.  It's simple and straightforward to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that using `window.btoa()` can be used to safely post this property.

```
var data = {
   workflowID: workflowToSave.ID,
   jsonWorkflow: window.btoa(JSON.stringify(workflowToSave))
};
```

Then in c# you can convert it back to a string like this:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(jsonDocument);
jsonDocument = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
jsonDocument = JsonPrettify(jsonDocument);
```

And then I'm able to just save it directly to a file.